# GLKit. How do I assign to a component of a GLKVector3

Tags: ios, macos, glkit

What is the correct way to assign to a field of a GLKVector3 (or 4)?

This fails:
[image]

Which makes sense since `.x` and `.z` are getters. What is the workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that in Swift `GLKVector3`s are immutable, whether a `var` or a `let`. Use `GLKVector3Make` to create one with arbitrary `Float` values; subsequently generate new results to new instances.

So:

```
let ballLocation = GLKVector3Make(
     (locationInBallCoordinates.x - ballCentre.x) / ballRadius,
     0.0,
     (locationInBallCoordinates.y - ballCentre.y) / ballRadius)
```

Or, if `locationInBallCoordinates` and `ballCentre` were already instances of `GLKVector3` — and the y-to-z component switch that I hadn't noticed when I first wrote this answer weren't there — then:

```
let ballLocation = 
    GLKVector3DivideScalar(
        GLKVector3Subtract(locationInBallCoordinates, ballCentre),
        ballRadius)
```

It's probably easiest to unpack and repack to move `y`s into `z`s but you could also use a matrix multiply if you were desperate to keep it high level.

Comment: Yah, I was afraid of that. Sigh. Makes for needlessly cumbersome/wordy code for trival set-ting operations like this. Onwards. Thx.

Comment: Ahh, actually I can overload +-/* to make things a bit more concise. Swift FTW.